# How to create a fader and bring an arbitrary element in front (to draw attention) in HTML5/CSS3?

Tags: html, css, css-position, z-index

I have a website and I'd like to have a mechanism where I create a 50% transparent black fader in front of *everything except one element* (no, the fader does **not** contain the child element) for the user to focus on that particular element for a brief period of time.

I've started with creating a fader with the following properties:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
z-index: 1000;
```

When I'm not using it, I add a class which sets it's `z-index` to -1 and it's hidden. When I remove the class, it's shown again. I can even add CSS animations to it. So far so good.

Now, suppose that I have an element, independent of this fader div, that I'd like to bring to front.

I've added `z-index: 1001` and nothing happened. Then, I've learned that I needed to add relative or absolute positioning to the element for z-index to work. I've added `position: relative` and it still doesn't work. I'm sure something else is not overriding the z-index or positioning properties. I confirm that my fader has *computed* absolute positioning and z index of 1000, and also the target object has a *computed* relative positioning and a z index of 1001. But it target is still hidden behind the fader.

Why?

(I've seen other questions regarding similar issues, but I haven't found an answer to this case in any of them. Most of them tell to use positioning to make z index work which I'm already doing.)

Comment: Can we see a simplified demo? Might help to see any hidden problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The z-index only affects elements that are placed other than `static`, (so either, `absolute`, `relative`, or `static`).

If no z-index is given the flow of the document specifies the stacking. In this demo, the second div stacks above the first one (natural flow).

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
#one {
  background: blue;
}
#two {
  top: 30px; left: 30px;
  background: red; 
}
```

```html
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
```

If we want to change that, we need to define a z-index:

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
#one {
  background: blue;
  z-index: 1;
}
#two {
  top: 30px; left: 30px;
  background: red; 
}
```

```html
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
```

But you got that part already.

The tricky part is when you use absolute or relative positions to both parents and child elements. The key is that **the `z-index` or a child can never be greater than it's parent.**.

In the following code `#one` is a child of `#parent`.

`#parent` has a z-index of `10`
`#one` has a z-index of `30`
`#two` has a z-index of `20`

So, you might expect the order (behind to above) to be

`#parent` > `#two` > `#one`
but since the z-index of `#one` can't be bigger that it's parent, it will be
`#parent` > `#one` > `#two`

```css
#parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background: yellow;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  z-index: 10
}
#one {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  background: blue;
  z-index: 30;
}
#two {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px; left: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  z-index: 20;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="one"></div>
</div>
<div id="two"></div>
```

Comment: I see. My problem is then something entirely different as any solution involving this fading mechanism would involve manipulation positioning and z-index attributes of the entire DOM tree of parents of the target (and possibly breaking *many, many* things). I'll try to figure out a different way then (maybe I'll add the fader dynamically as a sibling of the target element).

Comment: For future reference: I didn't know I was really close to the solution. Instead of DOM level, I've just added my fader to the parent of the target (in other words, as a sibling to the target). It worked with a small problem: the fader occupied the space of the container, not the whole page. I've had top/bottom/right/left set to 0px in the fader. I've changed them all to an absurdly large value (4000px) and it occupied the whole page without problem. All the z-indexes started to behave as intended and I've achieved my end result perfectly.

Comment: Maybe we could help, but therefor we need a (simplified) demo. Could you create a fiddle?

Comment: I actually solved the problem using your answer. I could prepare a fiddle but that would be the solution of the problem itself (and it would be weird if I've put the solution to the question itself)

Answer (score 0):

Make both of elements in absolute position
( position: absolute; )
it should solve this problem .
for Example :

```css
.red, .green, .blue {
  position: absolute;
}
.red {
  background: red;
  z-index: 1000;
  width : 50px;
  height : 50px;
}
.green {
  z-index: 1001;
  background: green;
  width : 50px;
  height : 50px;
}
.blue {
  z-index: 1002;
  background: blue;
  width : 50px;
  height : 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="red">Red</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="green">Green</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="blue">Blue</span>
</div>
```